# Stop the process on Android using Ruboto

Tags: android, ruby, irb, ruboto

Is it possible to Stop the process on Android using the script running in Ruboto's IRB, i.e. automate:
"Application manager" > "Running" > [Select process] > Press "Stop"?

Answer (score 0):

A process can stop itself by executing

```
java.lang.System.runFinalizersOnExit(true)
java.lang.System.exit(0)
```

You can stop another process with

```
Process.KillProcess(int pid)
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#killProcess%28int%29

You will need the KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES permission:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES